# Linefeed in comments

Tags: discussion, comments

In some cases I would like to have the possibility to use a linefeed in a comment, is there any way to do so? If i press enter the comment is posted immediatly.

Comment: no, also the formatting back end is network wide so would need to be raised at the general meta site, it could not be changed just for tex.sx. I expect this has been raised before though and declined.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-about-newlines-within-comments

Comment: Ok, I searched only for linefeed before posting the question. Maybe as a workaround I can use space if i want to structure a comment.

Comment: There are people using the double slash (//) for this purpose, but I find this more annoying than useful (and a single slash could be enough anyway).

Comment: You can use Shift-Enter to structure the _source_ of the comment, but that's about it. :/